# Change computed property with help of setter by click in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a modal in my template

```
<loading-modal:modal-state="openAddProductsModal.state"  title="Add New Products" size="lg" >
     <add-product  ref="addProduct" :@has-errors="openAddProductsModal.errors = $event" :"/>
       <div slot="footer">
         <btn  @click="$set(openAddProductsModal, state, false)">Cancel</btn>
           <btn :disabled="openAddProductsModal.errorAdd " type="primary" @click="save()">
           Save
         </btn>
       </div>
</loading-modal>
```

The I have also the computed property like this:

```
computed: {
   openAddProductsModal: {
     get() {
       this.errorAdd = true;
       return {state: this.$route.query.modal == 'open', errors: this.errorAdd}
     },
     set(newValue) {
       this.errorAdd = newValue.errors
       ModalState.setModalState(newValue.state, this.$route, this.$router, 'open')
     }
   },
}
```

What I want to is to change by clicking the button `Cancel` the property `state`, but it seems that it doesn't work - I tried also with `this.$set`. How could I call the setter method by clicking the button?

Comment: just use: `@click="openAddProductsModal = false"`

Comment: @ThomasKleßen I need to access both properties state and errors later and they could be different, so my idea was to have one onject with 2 different properties

Comment: Try `@click="() => { this.$set(this.openAddProductsModal, state, false) }"`